# Query to throw an error if a sanity check fails

Tags: postgresql

In writing a script intended to be run through psql (copy/pasted, or via '\i') I would like to include a sanity check - the transaction should abort if a certain query returns any rows -

```
select * from foos where is_bad_foo;  -- Abort transaction if any results
```

What's a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it into a function or an anonymous block:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_count
  from foo
  where is_bad_foo;
  if (l_count > 0) then
    raise exception 'too may rows';
  end if;
end;
$$
```

For details on the `raise` statement, see the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Comment: If you want to check for existence of a row, perhaps: "select case when exists (select null from foo where is_bad_foo) then 1 else 0 end;"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a stored procedure/function that takes the query you want to execute as an argument. 
Inside the procedure you checkif bad_foo has 0 records, and then execute the query. Else you exit.